# GridView with dynamic number of columns in each row

Tags: android

How can I recreate the following view with the help of a `GridView`.

[image]

The number of items in the list is dynamic.

Comment: a smaller image would have been nice :)

Comment: I don't think the GridView supports differnt # of columns, so AFAIK you'd have to "fake it" by splitting your images in half and setting one to each column for the rows that you want to appear as a single column. Out of curiosity why would you want to make this out of a GridView instead of a RelativeLayout or something that would make it easier to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that this is not a single GridView but a combination of multiple Layouts. Just make a LinearLayout and decide according to the content, which layout you want to have in a row.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar, but with a large number of elements in the row: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981294/gridview-like-android-widget-with-variable-lengths/

The drawback of using a layout is that when I scroll down, the bitmaps that go off the screen cannot be garbage collected. I would like to use the `GridView`'s ability to do that.

Comment: You can use a ListView so you get the rows itself recycled.

Comment: I can't use a `ListView` because my `View` needs to contain images with different heights.
It looks like I will need to develop my own custom control.

Comment: heights stretching over rows? Like table with colums/row span? Well than you need to do it on your own. Maybe make the resulting view available for others?

Comment: Yes, with a row span. I'll give it a try.

Comment: No luck doing it with a ScrollView with ImageViews inside.

When I remove the Bitmaps that go off the screen, and put them back when they go back, they don't come back. I asked part of it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123634/imageview-setimagebitmap-does-nothing-inside-complex-layout-inside-ontouch-inte

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the layout you see you can use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- First row -->
    <View />

    <!-- Second row -->
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <!-- Third row -->
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <!-- Fourth row -->
    <View />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want also the paged effect you can use a ViewPager

http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html