# GridView-like Android widget with variable lengths

Tags: android, android-gridview

Is there an existing Android widget third-party implementation that looks like a `GridView` but supports variable height items? I need one for images, but of course one that works with arbitrary views will work. Memory management is important, such that the Views and the bitmaps may be recycled.

Or, a way to convert `GridView` source code to do this?

An example of the grids:

> 1A 2A 3A
>
> 1A 2A 3B
>
> 1A 2B 3C

The first column contains 1 item labeled as 1A (relative height 1), the second one contains two items labeled as 2A (relative height 2/3) and 2B (relative height 1/3). The third column contains three items (all of them with relative height 1/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for something like VariableSizedWrapGrid in MS Windows 8. I think there is no a similar thing for Android. Maybe suggestions in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227597/gridview-with-dynamic-number-of-colums-in-each-row) will help you.