# ImageView setImageBitmap does nothing inside complex layout inside onTouch, intermittently

Tags: android, android-layout

I have nested layouts with ImageViews inside.
These are all inside a ScrollView.
Initially, the ImageViews are set to a Drawable resource.

I used this solution to detect scrolls. It's called from inside a `onTouchListener()`.
[Android: Detect when ScrollView stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling)

Inside the scroll listener, I update the ImageViews to load Bitmaps from files.

There are times (about 1 in 10?) where the `setImageBitmap` does noting. The Drawable resource is not replaced.

I tried the following:
* `requestLayout()` after `setImageBitmap()`
* `invalidate()` after `setImageBitmap()`
* posting the ImageView drawing logic to the UI thread separately