# Android different layout in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, row

I am very confused. How do I implement a gridview item like in this view?
[image]

Comment: Its a staggered GridView.  you can search for it and implement.

Comment: Refer this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227597/gridview-with-dynamic-number-of-colums-in-each-row

Comment: Use a `GridLayout`, instead

Answer (score 1):

try to look for  AsymmetricGridView https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView its a nice library. And easy to use.

more options :-

1. https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid
2. https://github.com/dchapkine/android-staggered-grid-demo

Comment: you can customize the code as per your requirement. No one can code for you.